# Fully expanding and distributing a symbolic sum

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, summation, algebraic-manipulation

I have quite a large expression I want to simplify. For example, this can be generated by a recursive definition:

```
x[1,m_] := x1[m];
x[m_, n_] := Sum[ x[m-1,k[m]+n] + x[m-1,k[m]-n], k[m] ];

R = x[5, 1]
```

The resulting expression contains several nested sums and in those sums are "additions" using `+` of several `x1[...]` with different indices. I want to rewrite this expression in terms of a sum (`+`) of nested multiple-`Sum`s where each if these multiple-`Sum` only contains a single `x1` with different indices.

So far, I have tried

```
Distribute @ (R //. {Sum[a_, b_] :> Sum[a // ExpandAll, b])
```

which works to some extent, but still leaves a few `+` untangled. (I.e. written inside of a `Sum`.)

### Edit: Sample output

The following output is generated for `x[5, 1]`:

```
 Sum[Sum[Sum[
      Sum[x1[1 + k[2] + k[3] + k[4] - k[5]] + 
         x1[-1 + k[2] - k[3] - k[4] + k[5]], k[2]] + 
       Sum[x1[1 + k[2] - k[3] + k[4] - k[5]] + 
         x1[-1 + k[2] + k[3] - k[4] + k[5]], k[2]], 
            k[3]] + 
     Sum[Sum[x1[1 + k[2] + k[3] - k[4] - k[5]] + 
         x1[-1 + k[2] - k[3] + k[4] + k[5]], k[2]] + 
       Sum[x1[1 + k[2] - k[3] - k[4] - k[5]] + 
         x1[-1 + k[2] + k[3] + k[4] + k[5]], 
                k[2]], k[3]], k[4]] + 
   Sum[Sum[Sum[
        x1[-1 + k[2] + k[3] + k[4] - k[5]] + 
         x1[1 + k[2] - k[3] - k[4] + k[5]], k[2]] + 
              
       Sum[x1[-1 + k[2] - k[3] + k[4] - k[5]] + 
         x1[1 + k[2] + k[3] - k[4] + k[5]], k[2]], k[3]] + 
          Sum[
      Sum[x1[-1 + k[2] + k[3] - k[4] - k[5]] + 
         x1[1 + k[2] - k[3] + k[4] + k[5]], k[2]] + 
       Sum[x1[-1 + k[2] - k[3] - k[4] - k[5]] + 
         x1[1 + k[2] + k[3] + k[4] + k[5]], k[2]], k[3]], 
        k[4]], k[5]]
```

Comment: Definitely a sample input with the desired output would be helpful here.  As is, running your code produces an expression that doesn't have any `Sum[ ... ]` expressions in it to begin with, so it's hard to figure out what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @march There was a typo